# Send data through API and update database on reciever side Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a project which has two databases. One for the Clientside and one for the Admin side. whenever the Database updated on the Admin side, it should update the Clientside databse. Both sides have different repositories. I am using the Observer for this. in my observer I am using this

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/observer2/public/api/view",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
         CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($customer),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
        "postman-token: 08f91779-330f-bf8f-1a64-d425e13710f9"
      ),
    ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
```

In my Clientside I am getting the data from API and it's fine. Both databases have some common tables with the same name. when I try to get the data on the receiver's end and try to update the data on the database, it gives me an error that ID already exists it means on receiver's end it uses Sender's database to search and update data. here is my controller of the receiver's end.

```
 public function savedata(Request $request){
        echo "in observer 2 project";

        $customer = new Customer;
        $customer->id = $request->id;
        $customer->name = $request->name;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->country = $request->country;
        if($customer->save()){
            return "1";
        }else{
            return "0";
        }

    }
```

Any body can help me what i am missing here???

Comment: nevermind... i just run php artisan config:cache and it works ;)